Azure WebAPI Authorization
I have a web API, which exposes some endpoints. I have deployed my application in Azure container App's env. and trying to authorize it with MS Entra ID. My client application is a service.  as per MS documentation, each app (Web API and client app) must have an application registration in MS EntraID. Web API app registration should have app roles and client app registration should have access to those roles.
Here is my scenario.

Web API deployed in ACA. Created an app registration ("AppReg_demoApp_1") for it. This app registration has an app role "demoprofile.reader". This app role is being authorized by the endpoint too.

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('APPROLE_demoprofile.reader')")
     @GetMapping("/user")
     public String helloWorldReader() {
         String caller = "TEst Caller Reader >>>>";
        System.out.println("Called by " + caller);
        return "{\r\n"
                + "  \"response\": \"Hello World Reader\"\r\n"
                + "}";
    }

Web API's application.yml has following
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MY_TENANT_ID>/v2.0


Created a second app registration (AppReg_demoApp_2) for the client app. My client app is a service. Provided API permissions to the first app registration like below. I created a client secret on this registration.



I am using client_credentials oAuth2 flow to authorize. For this, I used MSAL library and created a JWT token using client secret from client's app registration i.e.AppReg_demoApp_2 . When I try to access the endpoint, I keep getting 401 unauthorized.

Could anyone please let me know if my understanding for the app registration and set up of these apps is correct ?
What else do I need to do to make the call successful ?

Verify that the access token you are using to call the API is valid and has the necessary permissions to access the API. You can use a tool like jwt.io to decode the access token and verify its contents.
